# product topology inheritance

Tags: general-topology

> Question:
>   Show that if A is a subspace of X and B is a subspace of Y, then the product topology on $A \times B$ is the same as the topology $A \times B $inherits as a subspace of $X \times Y$.

Here's my attempt:

Let $\left ( X,T \right ),\left ( Y,U \right )$ be topological space.
A is a subspace of X so this implies that there is a subspace topology $\alpha=\left \{ v\cap A \mid v \in T \right \}$ on A.

B is a subspace of Y so we expect, again, $\beta=\left \{ e\cap B \mid e \in U \right \}$

The product topology on $A \times B$ is the topology generated by the basis $B=\alpha \times \beta =\left \{ a \times b \mid a \in \alpha, b \in \beta \right \}$

Would someone tell me if I am on the right track?

Hints are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems fine. You now have to show that the topology generated by $\alpha\times \beta$ (to use your notation) agrees with the subspace topology a.k.a. the topology which contains of the sets 
$$ U\cap A\times B\subset X\times Y, $$
where $U\subset X\times Y$ is a open set in the product topology of $X\times Y$.

*Hint:* First make an argument that it suffices to check this property on the generators $a\times b\in \alpha\times \beta$ respectively $U\times W \subset X\times Y$ where $U\subset X$ and $W\subset Y$ are open sets in their respective spaces. Make this argument by using the distributive properties of intersection and union of sets.

Now if you write down what you have to show it is basically automatic since for set of this form you have

$$ a\times b\cap U\times W=(a\cap U)\times (b\cap W). $$

Use this to complete the argument.

Let me know if you need any more help.